# Using pandas.read_sql_query with PostgreSQL returns Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

Here is the code:

```
sql = "select to_char(f_date at time zone 'GMT-8', 'YYYY-MM-DD 
       HH24:MI:SS')  as f_date, f_open, f_close, f_high, f_low, f_volume 
       from choice_kwindminutefinancehistory 
       INNER JOIN choice_financecode 
             ON choice_kwindminutefinancehistory.f_code_id=choice_financecode.id 
       where choice_financecode.f_code = '" + stock + "' 
             AND f_date >='" + start_date + "' and f_date<='" + end_date + "'"

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=self.engine)
```

This works totally fine, I got a dataframe from the query, but when I changed the SQL(added two more inner join), like this:

```
sql = "select to_char(kwm.f_date at time zone 'GMT-8', 'YYYY-MM-DD 
       HH24:MI:SS') as f_date , kwm.f_open as f_open, kwm.f_close as f_close, 
       kwm.f_high as f_high, kwm.f_low as f_low, kwm.f_volume as f_volume, 
       dfh.f_date as pre_date, dfh.f_open as pre_open, dfh.f_close as pre_close, 
       dfh.f_high as pre_high, dfh.f_low as pre_low, dfh2.f_volume as today_volumn 
       from choice_kwindminutefinancehistory as kwm 
       INNER JOIN choice_financecode as fc ON kwm.f_code_id=fc.id 
       INNER JOIN choice_dailyfinancehistory as dfh ON kwm.f_code_id = dfh.f_code_id 
             and dfh.f_date = '" + pre_date + "' 
       INNER JOIN choice_dailyfinancehistory as dfh2 ON kwm.f_code_id = dfh2.f_code_id 
             and dfh2.f_date = '" + start_date + "' 
       where fc.f_code = '" + stock + "' AND kwm.f_date >= '" + start_date + "' 
       and kwm.f_date<='" + end_date + "'"
```

I got an EMPTY Dataframe. Then I print the SQL on screen, copied and pasted it to DataGrip, the SQL worked, it can return rows, but in the programme, using `read_sql_query()` it returns empty, I don't know why.

Comment: Can you add your **programme**?

Comment: try breaking the query and executing part by part..i think you will figure out why its not giving the result

Comment: Shouldn't `and dfh.f_date = '" + pre_date + "'`  and `and dfh2.f_date = '" + start_date + "'` rather be part of the `WHERE` clause? Currently they belong to the `INNER JOIN` clauses, which looks fishy. Also, better refrain from [manually formatting query strings](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153500).

Comment: @SarthakNegi The query string works fine, it can give the right result, it's only when I use read_sql_query() function, it didn't work,

Comment: @shmee The query works fine, and it gives the result what I want, the problem is it returns nothing when I use pandas.read_sql_query() function.

Comment: I meant that just for test purpose break the query and pass it to read_sql_query part by part..if it returns the result for say first part then execute next until you get the part because of which read_sql_query is returning nothing

Comment: @SarthakNegi I tried that. When query string contains two `inner join` it goes empty, I still don't know why. I wonder if it is `read_sql_query()` problem not the query strinng